# How to express complex $sum grouping expression in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have following MongoDB aggregation query that works well in MongoDB

```
   [
     { $match: { "myfield":"X" },
     { $group: {
           _id: { myfield: "$myfield"  },
           count: { $sum: 1 },
           lt5w: { $sum: { $cond:{ if: { $gte: [ "$myDate", new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 5) ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } },
           gt12w: { $sum: { $cond:{ if: { $gte: [ new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 12), "$myDate"  ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } }
         }
     }
])
```

How can I express this complex $sum operation using Spring Data MongoDB API?

```
group("myfield))
    .sum("???").as("lt5w")
    .sum("???").as("gt12w")
    .count().as("count"),
```

The sum() method only expects simple string.
According to this ticket (closed)
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-784
the aggregation should support complex operations like $cmp and $cond

Update: It seems that the sum(AggregationExpression expr) version of the method is forgotten [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GroupOperation.java#L154). min(), max(), first() have that method version.

Answer (score 2):

Filed a ticket and the issue is fixed!

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1784